# how to force immediate writes to a disk from our own driver on linux

Tags: linux, caching, kernel, linux-device-driver, disk

We have a driver writing data directly to sectors of disk by sending the BIO through “make_request_fn” of other block device from block layer.

But somehow the data did not write down to the disk instantly, when I reboot the machine, the data what I wrote to disk before reboot are gone.

The data can reflect correctly on next reboot ONLY if one of following , before reboot,

1. I use function to flush the block device (from program) after writing
2. Drop the system cache by “fsyhc ; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches” after writing

We also tried following ways, but they all did not work.

1. Adding flag like flush/FUA on BIO flag
2. Calling blkdev_issue_flush()

This happened on both real machine and virtual environment like VMware.
OS is Ubuntu 14.4.3, with kernel 3.19 and Ext4 file system.

I am wondering if somebody can **explain the reason and help me out.**